# Apache Camel Netty

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I have CLIENT application which sends messages of the following format to TCP socket:

- first line is text line ended with `\r\n`and contains FILE size
- rest of message is binary (FILE)

At the end, CLIENT close connection.

On the SERVER side I want to process this message by use of `apache camel` route with `camel:netty4` endpoint. I don't now how to aggregate whole message from CLIENT because `camel:netty4` decoder process message part by part and camel create new exchange for each part.

Comment: I used aggregation with "CamelNettyRemoteAddress" as CorrelationExpression by now I don't now how to stop aggregating on client disconnect

Comment: You should most likely write a custom codec to use with netty, then you would get the whole message as one exchange. Here's an example project for that https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter6/netty

Comment: StefanR, thanks. Your answer is not solving my problem because I have still multiple chunks per one client application call. Imagine, that your client sends huge file. Then TCP protocol split your message into multiple chunks each of witch is processed separately (new exchange per chunk). That's why I need aggregator.